# API support in Play Store

Tags: api, google-play

Good day, today I uploaded my application to google play, and in the stability section of my application it appeared that I have a compatibility problem of an APi which unfortunately I do not know which of all it is, it threw the following error: **Landroid / graphics / Typeface; -> sSystemFontMap: Ljava / util / Map**, and then they added the following:

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->sSystemFontMap:Ljava/util/Map;
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:416)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.TextViewHelper.getSystemFontMap(TextViewHelper.java:3)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.TextViewHelper.<clinit>(TextViewHelper.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.TextViewHelper.getTextOfTextViewOrEmpty(TextViewHelper.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.EspressoElement.extractDescription(EspressoElement.java:4)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.EspressoElement.create(EspressoElement.java:2)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.ViewScreenStateBuilder$ViewTreeNode.<init>(ViewScreenStateBuilder.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.ViewScreenStateBuilder.traverseAndBuild(ViewScreenStateBuilder.java:5)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.HybridStateExtractor.tryExtractingScreenState(HybridStateExtractor.java:9)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.HybridStateExtractor.getStableScreen(HybridStateExtractor.java:2)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.handlePerformScrape(RemotePlatform.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.messageLoop(RemotePlatform.java:27)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform.lambda$startCrawlAndWaitUntilFinished$0$RemotePlatform(RemotePlatform.java:1)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.RemotePlatform$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

What Api are you referring to? What could I do to fix this? Maybe what I'm asking is obvious but I'm new to this.
Thanks so much for reading.

Comment: Is your app a jetpack compose app, by any chance?

Answer (score -1):

Same for me.
Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->sSystemFontMap:Ljava/util/Map;
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->sSystemFontMap:Ljava/util/Map;

I don´t know what is this, may be a problem to be resolved by flutter.